# Local Host not succesful

Tags: node.js, localhost

[Command Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZHFj.png)

Above I have a screen shot of my app.js server and for some reason the connection is not going through below I have my app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Adil@123',
  database: 'movies'

});
mysqlConnection.connect(err=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log('It was not successful \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
  } else {
    console.log('Its a success');
  }
  });
 //  Collecting all the movies from the movielist
  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 // Finding a movie based on the `idmovielist` number
   app.get('/movielist',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err, rows,fields) =>{
    if (!err) {
      res.send(rows);
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });

  // Delting a movie
   app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
  // Inserting a movie
  app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (`idmovielist`,`name`,`thumnail_path`,`description`,`language_released`,`year_released`) VALUES ('"+req.body.idmovielist+"', '"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.thumnail_path+"', '"+req.body.description+"', '"+req.body.year_released+"', '"+req.body.language_released+"' )",
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});

// Updating the movie list
app.put('/movielist/:id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET `year_released` WHERE = '"+update.idmovielist+"','"+update.year_released+"'",
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});


// localhost:3000
app.listen(3000,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = app;
```

Above is my app.js the server was working earlier but for some reason it is not working anymore what can be the issue Is it something wrong with my code or should I change the port or create another server

Comment: The screenshot says you are listening on port 3006, but your code says 3000.

Comment: const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

Comment: @SamCurry this is my server code and it has a port of 3000

Comment: port `3306` is mysql port. check if your mysql service is running

Comment: @1556089774 the database is in mysql workbench but my myswl bench is not opening

Comment: Never worked with workbench, google on how to start, use etc

Comment: @1556089774 this server was working yesterday and all of the sudden it decides not to work